# How to make remote REST call inside Node.js? any CURL?

Tags: rest, curl, node.js

In **Node.js**, other than using child process to make **CURL** call, is there a way to make CURL call to remote server **REST** API and get the return data?

I also need to set up the request header to the remote **REST** call, and also query string as well in GET (or POST).

I find this one: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

but it doesn't show any way to POST query string.

Comment: I wrote this https://github.com/jonataswalker/vps-rest-client

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Look at [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

```
var options = {
  host: url,
  port: 80,
  path: '/resource?id=foo&bar=baz',
  method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
```

Comment: So, even it is POST, I also append data in the query string?

Comment: @murvinlai not sure. Go read the docs, source, HTTP spec. Not an expert on that region.

Comment: Version 6.18 docs : http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: One thing to note is that you don't put http or https in your host entry e.g. var options = { host: graph.facebook.com .... } not {host: http: graph.facebook.com }.  That tripped me up for a few cycles.  (See below).  These are both great answers.  Thanks to you both.

Comment: Can I just point out that if the reply is long, using res.on('data',..) is not enough. I believe the correct way is to also have res.on('end'..) to know when you have received all the data. Then you can process.

Comment: This is a very old answer - for those writing node js today you'd surely use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch or other fetch API based package, which is based on the Fetch standard. See my answer below.

Comment: Could you mention how you called the http module? require('WHAT?')

Comment: @user3072843, it's there in the link mentioned. require('node-fetch');

Answer (score 97):

How about using [Request — Simplified HTTP client](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

**Edit February 2020: Request has been deprecated so you probably shouldn't use it any more.**

Here's a GET:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
     }
})
```

OP also wanted a POST:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
```

Comment: Works fine with google.com but returning "RequestError: Error: socket hang up" when requesting facebook's graph api. Please guide, thanks!

Comment: This module contains a lot of issues!

Comment: How can I pass a request parameter while consuming a REST API in this way?

Comment: As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully DEPRECATED. You can see it in the website https://github.com/request/request#deprecated

Comment: Any guidance on what newbies should use?  I am filtering thru a LOT of examples that use this.

Comment: This provides some guidance: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143

Comment: Depracated a while ago

Answer (score 54):

I use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) because it uses the familiar (if you are a web developer) [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). fetch() is the new way to make arbitrary HTTP requests from the browser.

Yes I know this is a node js question, but don't we want to reduce the number of API's developers have to memorize and understand, and improve re-useability of our javascript code? [Fetch is a standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) so how about we converge on that?

The other nice thing about `fetch()` is that it returns a javascript [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can write async code like this:

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('http://localhost', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: '{}'
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).catch(err => {console.log(err);});
```

Fetch superseeds [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Here's some [more info](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/).

Comment: problem with `node-fetch` when writting APIs is that only works will full URL and will not work with relative URLs.

Comment: Note: fetch() is coming to the core NodeJS runtime as of v17.5 https://fusebit.io/blog/node-fetch/

Answer (score 41):

Look at http://isolasoftware.it/2012/05/28/call-rest-api-with-node-js/

```
var https = require('https');

/**
 * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
 */
// options for GET
var optionsget = {
    host : 'graph.facebook.com', // here only the domain name
    // (no http/https !)
    port : 443,
    path : '/youscada', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
    // console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

/**
 * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - POST
 */
// do a POST request
// create the JSON object
jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
    "message" : "The web of things is approaching, let do some tests to be ready!",
    "name" : "Test message posted with node.js",
    "caption" : "Some tests with node.js",
    "link" : "http://www.youscada.com",
    "description" : "this is a description",
    "picture" : "http://youscada.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/logo2.png",
    "actions" : [ {
        "name" : "youSCADA",
        "link" : "http://www.youscada.com"
    } ]
});

// prepare the header
var postheaders = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
};

// the post options
var optionspost = {
    host : 'graph.facebook.com',
    port : 443,
    path : '/youscada/feed?access_token=your_api_key',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : postheaders
};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionspost);
console.info('Do the POST call');

// do the POST call
var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
//  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('POST result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
    });
});

// write the json data
reqPost.write(jsonObject);
reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

/**
 * Get Message - GET
 */
// options for GET
var optionsgetmsg = {
    host : 'graph.facebook.com', // here only the domain name
    // (no http/https !)
    port : 443,
    path : '/youscada/feed?access_token=you_api_key', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsgetmsg);
console.info('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = https.request(optionsgetmsg, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
//  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result after POST:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: How do i access the values from d??? d = {"data":[{"id":1111,"name":"peter"}]} . how to get name value?

Comment: managed to get values by using var thed = JSON.parse(d);
  console.log("the id is : "+thed.data[0].id);      
But some time i get "Unexpected end of input"

Answer (score 20):

#### Axios

An example (axios_example.js) using Axios in Node.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    let query = req.query.queryStr;
    let url = `https://your.service.org?query=${query}`;

    axios({
        method:'get',
        url,
        auth: {
            username: 'the_username',
            password: 'the_password'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(port);
```

Be sure in your project directory you do:

```
npm init
npm install express
npm install axios
node axios_example.js
```

You can then test the Node.js REST API using your browser at: `http://localhost:5000/search?queryStr=xxxxxxxxx`

Similarly you can do post, such as:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://your.service.org/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

#### SuperAgent

Similarly you can use SuperAgent.

```
superagent.get('https://your.service.org?query=xxxx')
.end((err, response) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response.body));
});
```

And if you want to do basic authentication:

```
superagent.get('https://your.service.org?query=xxxx')
.auth('the_username', 'the_password')
.end((err, response) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response.body));
});
```

#### Ref:

- https://github.com/axios/axios
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Answer (score 11):

I have been using [restler](https://npmjs.org/package/restler) for making webservices call, works like charm and is pretty neat.

Answer (score 5):

**Warning: As of Feb 11th 2020, [request](https://github.com/request/request) is fully deprecated.**

One another example - you need to install request module for that

```
var request = require('request');
function get_trustyou(trust_you_id, callback) {
    var options = {
        uri : 'https://api.trustyou.com/hotels/'+trust_you_id+'/seal.json',
        method : 'GET'
    }; 
    var res = '';
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res = body;
        }
        else {
            res = 'Not Found';
        }
        callback(res);
    });
}

get_trustyou("674fa44c-1fbd-4275-aa72-a20f262372cd", function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To use latest Async/Await features

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise-native
```

//code

```
async function getData (){
    try{
          var rp = require ('request-promise-native');
          var options = {
          uri:'https://reqres.in/api/users/2',
          json:true
        };

        var response = await rp(options);
        return response;
    }catch(error){
        throw error;
    }        
}

try{
    console.log(getData());
}catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: this library is deprecated ❗

Answer (score 4):

```
const http = require('http');
const url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(response) {
  let finalData = "";

  response.on("data", function (data) {
    finalData += data.toString();
  });

  response.on("end", function() {
    console.log(finalData.length);
    console.log(finalData.toString());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any with cURL so I wrote a wrapper around [node-libcurl](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl) and can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vps-rest-client.

To make a POST is like so:

```
var host = 'https://api.budgetvm.com/v2/dns/record';
var key = 'some___key';
var domain_id = 'some___id';

var rest = require('vps-rest-client');
var client = rest.createClient(key, {
  verbose: false
});

var post = {
  domain: domain_id,
  record: 'test.example.net',
  type: 'A',
  content: '111.111.111.111'
};

client.post(host, post).then(function(resp) {
  console.info(resp);

  if (resp.success === true) {
    // some action
  }
  client.close();
}).catch((err) => console.info(err));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Node.js 4.4+, take a look at [reqclient](https://github.com/mrsarm/reqclient), it allows you to make calls and log the requests in *cURL* style, so you can easily check and reproduce the calls outside the application.

Returns [Promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) objects instead of pass simple callbacks, so you can handle the result in a more *"fashion"* way, [chain](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/09/28/chaining-promises-in-javascript.aspx) the result easily, and handle errors in a standard way. Also removes a lot of boilerplate configurations on each request: base URL, time out, content type format, default headers, parameters and query binding in the URL, and basic cache features.

This is an example of how to initialize it, make a call and log the operation with **curl** style:

```js
var RequestClient = require("reqclient").RequestClient;
var client = new RequestClient({
    baseUrl:"http://baseurl.com/api/", debugRequest:true, debugResponse:true});
client.post("client/orders", {"client": 1234, "ref_id": "A987"},{"x-token": "AFF01XX"});
```

This will log in the console...

```
[Requesting client/orders]-> -X POST http://baseurl.com/api/client/orders -d '{"client": 1234, "ref_id": "A987"}' -H '{"x-token": "AFF01XX"}' -H Content-Type:application/json
```

And when the response is returned ...

```
[Response   client/orders]<- Status 200 - {"orderId": 1320934}
```

This is an example of how to handle the response with the promise object:

```js
client.get("reports/clients")
  .then(function(response) {
    // Do something with the result
  }).catch(console.error);  // In case of error ...
```

Of course, it can be installed with: `npm install reqclient`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update from 2022:**

from node.js version v18 on you can use the globally available `fetch` API (see https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/)

There is also an example usage included on their announcement page:

```
const res = await fetch('https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.json');
if (res.ok) {
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curlrequest](https://github.com/chriso/curlrequest) to easily set what time of request you want to do... you can even set headers in the options to "*fake*" a browser call.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: As of Feb 11th 2020, [request](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) is fully deprecated.**

If you implement with form-data, for more info (https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/07/27/multipart-post-request-using-node.js):

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
  formData: {
    file: fs.createReadStream('sample.zip'),
    token: '### access token ###',
    filetype: 'zip',
    filename: 'samplefilename',
    channels: 'sample',
    title: 'sampletitle',
  },
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found superagent to be really useful,
it is very simple
for example

```
const superagent=require('superagent')
superagent
.get('google.com')
.set('Authorization','Authorization object')
.set('Accept','application/json')
```