# Making REST call from Node.js and sending response to browser

Tags: node.js, rest

I am beginner to Node.js, so as per project requirements I am trying to call REST service from Node.js, I got information of how to call rest from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl). Here is the code to make rest call:

```
var options = {
 host: url,
 port: 80,
 path: '/resource?id=foo&bar=baz',
 method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk); //I want to send this 'chunk' as a response to browser
  });
}).end();
```

The problem is I want to send `chunk` as a response to a browser, I tried `res.write()` but it is throwing me error "write method not found". I looked in docs everywhere, but all they give is console.log. Can anyone let me know how can I send that data as a response to a browser?

Comment: Downvoter: Add an explanatory comment, so that I can correct if "you" feel there is wrong in the question. As I have clearly mentioned I am beginner, you should have a sense to mention whats wrong in this question before downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `http.request` is an instance of `IncomingMessage`, which is a `Readable` Stream that doesn't have a `write` method. When making an HTTP request with `http.request`, you cannot send a response. HTTP is a request-response-message-oriented protocol.

> how can I send that data as a response to a browser?

For a browser to be able to get response, it must make a request first. You'll have to have a server running which calls the REST service when it receives a request.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var data = getDataFromREST(function(data) {
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });

});
```