# Fill an array based on a get response express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have the following server.js get route

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var url;
var final_res = [];
endpoints.forEach(function(url){
    request(url, function(error,response,body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            final_res.push(url.url);
            console.log(url.url);
        }else{
            res.send(err);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And this is my client js where I fetch this exact same get with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('http://localhost:3000/', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#body").text(data);
});
});
```

When I open my index.html it displays the user interface correctly and inside my terminal where I have executing my server.js it correctly displays the url. What I can't accomplish is how to use my data that my jQuery receives in order to populate a table inside my html. My table will be populated with urls that are fetch from my endpoints.

I have some background in nodejs but I cant wrap this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to know when multiple requests are done, I'd suggest you switch to using the request-promise library so you can use promises to track when all the requests are done. That library also checks the statusCode for you automatically.  So, you can do this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Promise.all(endpoints.map(url => {
        return rp(url).then(r => {
            return url.url;
        }).catch(err => {
            // rather than error, just return null result
            return null;
        })
    })).then(results => {
        // filter out null values, then send array as the response
        res.json(results.filter(item => item !== null));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

This will run all the requests in parallel, but collect the results in order which should result in the fastest overall run time.

If you wanted to run them one a time, you could use async/await like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    let results = [];
    for (let url of endpoints) {
        try {
            let r = await rp(url);
            if (r) {
                results.push(url.url);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            // ignore error
        }
    }
    res.json(results);
});
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Comment: Awesome it look cleaner using promises the only issue I'm having now is I'm getting a CORS error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). I dont understand why if my node is making the request and im only calling my endpoint that fetches this information @jfriend00

Comment: @user2737948 - Are you getting the CORs error in the browser?  If so, what does the browser show in the URL bar for the page where you're making the ajax request?

Comment: I open my index in another window and is pointing out the the address from my documents. Is it necessary to have my index inside my nodejs server?

Comment: @user2737948 - You did not answer either of the questions I asked in my previous comment and I have no idea what your last comment means.  If you want to make an Ajax call to `http://localhost:3000`, then you need to also load the web page from that same server so that the URL in the browser starts with `http://localhost:3000`.  If you are loading the web page from the file system directly, you cannot do Ajax to `http://localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for all requests gets resolved to then send `final_res` array back to client. You can do this using `async/await` and `Promise.all` concepts. If you don't want to use these resources then you'll need to count and wait all request manually, using a counter to know when all requests has done, as below:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var url;
    var final_res = [];
    var respCounter = endpoints.length;
    endpoints.forEach(function(url){
        request(url, function(error,response,body){
            respCounter--;
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                final_res.push(url.url);
                console.log(url.url);
            }else{
                res.send(err);
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(respCounter == 0) {
                res.send(final_res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```