# How to get value from php variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am working on a project attendance system and i want to access a variable that is declared in php file require.php in my node.js file custom.js how should i achieve that? so far i have created a connection with my sql server and hard-coded the value of

```
`var company_name="Aaqoo 2";`
```

and everything is working fine but i dont want to hard-code it i want to fetch the company_name stored in my php variable $sup_company_name which is declared in my require.php file so my question is how should i fetch the value from $sup_company_name in my js variable.....kindly help me then i will ask futher questions

this is my node js code

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'attendance'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (!!error) {
    console.log('Error in connection');
    } else {
    console.log('Connected');  
    }
});
var company_name = "Aaqoo 2"; //here i want the value from php variable $sup_company_name;

connection.query("Select * from employee_leaves where employee_leave_company_name=?", [company_name], function(error,rows,fields) {
    if (!!error) {
        console.log("Error in the query");
    } else {
        console.log("succesfully done\n");
        console.log(rows);
    }
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `var company_name= '<?php echo $sup_company_name; ?>'`

Comment: @Oluwafemi but the issue is $sup_company_name is in require.php file and when i include the require php file using include("require.php"); node.js gives me error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: PHP is executed before JavaScript. Include your PHP file via PHP first, then echo the variable value

Comment: @Oluwafemi SyntaxError: Unexpected token <? ?>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

Comment: @Dacaspex i have included it before like <?include("require.php");and then i have written the javascript within thw script tags

Comment: You open a PHP tag with `<?php` and close it with `?>` You opened it with `<?`

Comment: @Dacaspex it doesn't create any difference u can either use <??> or <?php    ?> both are same things

Comment: You can create a PHP API and consume it in your node.js file to get the value of `$sup_company_name` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl

Comment: @Oluwafemi should i use ajax to fetch the value

Comment: Yes you can since node.js supports javascript.

Comment: @Oluwafemi brother ok let me try that

Comment: it dint work either this time the error was $.ajax not supported

Answer (score 1):

I did it, This is my example, only that i use this for my  conection with pgsql.

code node js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(
    'php -r \'include("require.php"); echo $companyname."#@#".$hostname."#@#".$username."#@#".$database."#@#".$password;\'',

  function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    var [ companyname,hostname,username, database, password ] = stdout.split('#@#');
    const connectionData = {
      user: username,
      host: '',
      database: database,
      password: password,
      port: 5432,
    }
    const client = new Client(connectionData)

    client.connect()
    client.query('Select * from employee_leaves where employee_leave_company_name=?',companyname)
        .then(response => {
            //console.log(response.rows)
            client.end()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            client.end()
        })
  }
);
```

require.php

```
$companyname= 'namecompany'; 
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'namedatabase';
$username = 'root';
$password = '123';
```