# Forever running processes on the Server

Tags: php, node.js, linux

I have to do some processing on the server, continuously, forever. I am thinking of using `GNU screen` to run this process in the background. I need to do some XMLHttp GET requests. Which would be the preferred languages to run this kind of forever running process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those languages (node.js & php) would be equal in their ability to make simple REST requests.

[How to make remote REST call inside Node.js? any CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl)

[Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)

Screen or forever would work. Another option is [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/), which lets you open multiple terminal panes that can keep running after you close them.