# how to import JSON data from rest API to google firebase?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to use Firebase as my backend service for the mobile application. As part of the functionality, I need to get the data from external rest API which returns JSON data. I need to update the data periodically so that I can have updated information.

I have an option to call the rest API and update firebase on the mobile application however it is not the right approach. I prefer to keep this logic on the backend service.

Is there a way to use Firebase cloud function to periodically update firebase database from external Rest API?

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This will help me trigger the call periodically. I am not sure how to call a rest API to get the JSON data in cloud function. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Cloud Functions are just Node.js code. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl

Comment: I m a newbie to firebase. I did not know that it is a node.js function. I will try it out, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Ioki, I assume what you are trying to do is make a mobile app which gets updated data *every time a user goes to the app* but you want this to be on the **backend**. I haven't tried it but you might want to use Node js with their Firebase Admin SDK.
See the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Although I think it might make more sense to use the real-time database via the iOS/ Android SDK because automatic/ value event updates are basically the purpose of the real- time database. Good luck! :)