# how to communicate among two separated APIs?

Tags: javascript, express

I want to communicate(I mean I want to get requests and send responses) among two  separated APIs(expressjs API) how should I do it.Is there anyone has a example or something?.I have a little knowledge  about  APIs...

Actually I have an expressjs REST api and php one.If you can explain it.it is worth.(there are two separated db and apis(one module has db and an api)..when one db is updated i want to update second db using those apis)

Comment: Unfortunatley you won't find a answer to your question here, because you ask to write somthing by explaining nothing

Comment: Do you mean REST apis? If so then it might be a duplicate to [How to make remote REST call inside Node.js? any CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321). If it is some other API you need to explain what kind of API it is.

Comment: Actually I have an expressjs REST api and php one.If you can explain it.it is worth.(there are two separated db and apis(one module has db and an api)..when one db is updated  i want to update second db using those apis)

Comment: Use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module to issue requests - almost same thing as when you issue AJAX requests from a browser